# Does D/L variation go back to a dl cluster?

Tags: etymology, consonants, old-latin

As outlined [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RtsLKLhCZ0EC&pg=PA318&lpg=PA318&dq=%22dl%22%20cluster%20%22lacrima%22&source=bl&ots=KsW0GGyZRb&sig=ACfU3U1dC24jAUyAhpAZOH0Wg2SLF8NcRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT9v3qjfjqAhV0OX0KHc4eBsYQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22dl%22%20cluster%20%22lacrima%22&f=false) in “Indo-European *d, *l and *dl” by Tim Pulju, there’s a hypothesis going back to Hamp 1972 that the l in Latin lacrima and d in the archaic variant dacruma both represent a dl cluster that derived in this word by long-distance dissimulation of r...r to l...r. (Compare longus for the development *dl > l.)

Pulju also explains *lēvir/laevir* as coming from a form with *dl: he says that in most other branches of IE, *dl was reduced here to *d, but Lithuanian *láigonas* "wife's brother" is supposed to show a sporadic reduction to *l instead (in contrast to Lithuanian *dieverìs* "husband's brother", also from the same root).
([Section 4.1 *dāiwēr 'husband's brother', page 317](https://books.google.com/books?id=RtsLKLhCZ0EC&pg=PA317#v=onepage&q&f=false))

However, the traditional explanation is that there was a sound change d > l (also in some other words like lingua), apparently not regular in Latin, but often attributed to influence from some other dialect.

What have other linguists said (preferably, more recently) about this topic?

---

Words that show *l* in place of *d* in Latin, taken from a list in "[Deltacism of laterals in Sino-Tibetan and elsewhere](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.567.4937&rep=rep1&type=pdf)", by James A. Matisoff:

- *[lacrima](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lacrima#Latin)*
- *[lingua](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lingua#Latin)*
- *[lēvir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/levir#Latin)*
- *[oleo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oleo)*

The name [Ulixēs](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=Ulixes), although it's unclear if the use of l goes back to a Greek dialectal variant.

Comment: I've also read that initial d > l was a regular sound change in Etruscan, though I'd have to search for a source on that.

Comment: Before we start analyzing relevant data in detail, can we have the entire list of such Latin words with this hypothetical - at least for now - word-initial *dl > l, along with the other Italic and IE comparanda please? One could use e.g. de Vaan to do that.

Comment: FWIW, Coleman (1990) adheres to the old "Sabine L" theory, without mentioning Hamp's idea: https://www.jstor.org/stable/44696679?seq=1

Comment: Link to Hamp 1972: https://www.jstor.org/stable/40266244?seq=1

Comment: Is your question about d/l (without any *dl reconstructions) or about uncontroversial cases of word-initial *dl > l (one word only, longus - based on IE reliable comparanda) or words of unknown etymology, like lingua and lacruma/lacrima (for which there could be ad hoc hypotheses only, e.g. Hamp PIE *dr > PIt. (?) dl > l)?

Comment: @AlexB.: I would say my question is about the various ways in which the d/l variation has been explained. *dl reconstruction is specifically Pulju's explanation (in the case of lacrima, going back to Hamp; Pulju also reconstructs *dl in the ancestor of levir/laevir and lac). I'd like to know alternative explanations also

Comment: I know about Hamp 1972. What are Pulju's PIE and PIt reconstructions for Latin levir (with page numbers please) ? I cannot find such *dl- reconstructions for Latin levir in his article.

Comment: I have virtually no knowledge of this topic, but, by chance, I've just [seen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calamitas#Latin) _ca**l**amitas_ comes from old-Latin _ka**d**amitas_  . I wonder if it has something to do with question.

Answer (score 14):

Bibliography on this phenomenon: [Poucet 1966:](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41673349) 140, supplemented by [Burman 2018](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/271510); if you have free time, you can also watch ["(False) Etymology and ‘Sabine -l-‘"](https://video.ku.dk/etymology-and-the-european-lexicon-part-30-false) by Nicholas Zair - he presented it at the 14th Fachtagung of the Indogermanische Gesellschaft in Copenhagen in 2012 (Etymology and the European Lexicon; you can skip the Q&A session at the end, it's not particularly informative).

### What do we have?

Indeed, a small number of Latin words have been identified (Bruno 1961 has 39) where one would expect *d* - based on their IE comparanda - but still encounters *l*. This is most irregular, based on what we know about Latin so far.

**NB:** A superficially similar change * -dl- > -ll is very different (it's **Inlaut** only and then we have a **geminate** *l* here, a very common sound change, assimilation). Sihler 1995 (section 223) writes:

> *dl, *ld, *nl, *ln, *rl, *ls  become L *ll*.

e.g. Weiss 2020 mentions *sella*, [grallae](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#45185), and [pelluuiae](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#66306), Sihler 1995 also has *sallo*. Most importantly, we have IE comparanda to justify *dl in these cases.

*Ulixes* is typically thought to reflect the Greek dialectal variation (Biville 1995, Weiss 2020: 504, footnote 65; cf. Sihler 1995 section 151).

### How to interpret our data?

Hypothetically, one could try to lump all these words together into a Proto-Italic (or 'proto-Latin') phonetic change/law of sorts or one could deal with the words individually or in smaller groups (ad-hoc).

In my opinion, it's all about the plausibility ("the a priori probability") of one's proposal. One needs to examine IE comparanda and how much sense one's proposal makes from what we know from linguistic typology, phonetics, and historical linguistics in general and of the IE family, the Italic group, and Latin itself.

For example, which reconstruction do you find more convincing, Kümmel's PIE *ɖ > PIE *d > Italic *d or  Kortland's PIE *t' > PIE *d' (except in Anatolian and Tocharian) > Italic *d?

So, we could continue interpreting this small subset of Latin words as some kind of **a dialectal/historical irregularity** (a current standard view) or substantially revise our models of Latin, Italic, and IE (and PIE) phonetics (I am aware of three such proposals only, [Schrijnen 1914](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40846645) (cf. Pulju 1995), Lehmann 1986 and Prósper 2019; thanks to Asteroides for bringing to my attention the work of Tim Pulju and Blanca María Prósper).

[Lehmann 1986](https://www.degruyter.com/view/book/9783110856132/10.1515/9783110856132.483.xml) argued that the d/l variation is a result of PIE d < t' (he subscribed to the glottalic theory). Lehmann himself called this change "an aberrant development." You can read about [the glottalic theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottalic_theory) e.g. in Wikipedia, if you don't know what it is, and decide for yourself.

[Pulju 1995](https://scholarship.rice.edu/handle/1911/16870) believes that "Irregular correspondences involving /d/ and /l/ provide evidence for the reconstruction of **a rare** PIE cluster *dl" [emphasis mine - Alex B.] that "was phonotactically disfavored and was therefore subject to sporadic modification throughout the IE language family." The *dl reconstruction in PIE is not new at all and goes back to [Schrijnen 1914](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40846645). I will leave it up to you to decide whether you find this argument convincing.

### A closer look at d/l Anlaut variation

I think it's extremely important to carefully examine relevant data with **d/l Anlaut variation** (all the etymological data is taken from de Vaan, unless stated otherwise):

> 1. PIE *d corresponds to Latin l (no need or data to reconstruct *dl, either for Proto-Italic or PIE):

[lēvir](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#55578) (laevir) 'husband's brother' < PIt. daiwēr < PIE deh2i-uer- 'husband's brother' (**Anlaut * d > l**)

**Italic comparanda:** not listed

**IE comparanda:**  Skt. devár-, Pashto lēvar, Gr. δᾱήρ, Arm. taygr, Lith. díeveris / dieverìs, Latv. diẽveris, Ru. déver', SCr. djȅvēr < BSl. * daʔiu̯er-; OHG zeihhur, OE tācor 'husband's brother' < PGm. * taikura-(?).

**NB:** *dl reconstructions are very unusual, cf. Schrijnen 1914 *dlai̯u̯er (Pulju 1995 *dlāiwēr) His evidence? It is entirely based on one Lithuanian word, *laigonas*. (I didn't look it up yet myself). Obviously he has to 'explain' how the "objectionable" and "rare" *dl cluster was lost in all the IE languages.

cf. Weiss 2020: 504; also [oleo](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#62714) and solium (NB: these two words are examples of **intervocalic * d > l**) - [Matisoff 2013](https://doi.org/10.1075/tsl.103.05mat) calls this "internal ‑d‑ � ‑l‑ variation within Latin" or [Zair 2012](https://fachtagung.ku.dk/Konferencebog.pdf) ""synchronic -d-/-l- variation" (p. 129).

de Vaan writes [s.v. odor](https://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search#dictionary=latin&id=la1139): "Some forms show the change of intervocalic * d > l, the exact conditions of which are unclear. In this word, it seems that d was preserved in front of ō, but changed to l in front of ē. In view of fulgēre / fulgere, fervēre / fervere, it seems likely that olĕre is older than olēre (cf. Leumann)."

> 2. PIE *dl corresponds to Latin l (via a putative reconstructed *dl stage in Proto-Italic):

[longus](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#56415) < PIt. *(d)longo- < PIE *dlong<sup>h</sup>-o-, the only (?) Anlaut example, cf. Weiss 2020: 178 (**Anlaut * dl > l**)

**Italic comparanda:** not listed - how robust is this Proto-Italic reconstruction that is based on one Latin word only? (that being said, take a look at its PIE comparanda below, esp. Skt., OAv. vs. OCS, Greek vs. Hittite)

**IE comparanda:** Skt. dīrghá-, OAv. darəga-, OCS dlъgъ, SCr. dȕg, Lith. ìlgas, Alb. gjatë 'long' (+ *-tā-); Gr. δολιχός; Hit. * taluki- / talugai- [adj.] 'long'; Hit. zaluknu-zi 'to lengthen' etc.

**Phonetic change:** total contact regressive assimilation

> 3. PIE *d corresponds to Lat. l (d?)

two Latin words with solid IE cognates and an unclear development in Latin/Italic, lingua and lacruma

[lacruma](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#54309) (dacruma - three attestations only, all by the grammarians only - [Mar. Vict., Keil 6.26.2](https://archive.org/details/p1grammaticilatini06keil/page/26/mode/2up)) (**Anlaut l/d variation**)

lacruma < PIt. *d(r)(k)akrunā-? < PIE *drḱ-h2(e)ḱru- 'eye-bitter' (Kortlandt 1985b)

**Italic comparanda:** not listed

**IE comparanda:** Skt. áśru-, YAv. asrū [pl.], Gr. δάκρυ, Arm. artasuk' [pl.], Lith. ãšara, OHG zahar, ToB akrūna [obl.pl.] 'tear';    OIr. dér, W. deigr 'tear', Hit. išhahru- [n.] 'tear(s), weeping'

Beekes: "A Hell. form *δάκρῠμα is often assumed to be the source of Lat. dacrŭma, lacrĭma, but see now the discussion in De Vaan 2008 s.v. dacruma ."

Attestations of δάκρῡμα -ατος, τό: Beekes: δάκρῡμα 'mourned for' (Orac. apud Hdt. 7, 169), 'tear' (A.): cf. Montanari (BDAG): tear, lament Aeschl. Pers. 134; Eur. Andr. 92 ( pl. ); cause of weeping: Opp. ( Hdt. 7.169.2) .

cf. pl. δάκρη (δάκρῠ)

Re: δάκρῡμα < *δάκρῠμα in Greek, see Biville 1995: 28-29, 128

**Phonetic changes**:

1. a Greek loan borrowed via another Italic language(s), traditionally explained  via "Sabine", starting with [Conway 1893](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/indo/2/1/article-p157.xml), who used the elimination principle; cf. *lepesta(e)* in Biville "Le passage du grec δ- au l- latin serait un sabinisme", II: 100 or I: 74, ft. 21)

What is "Sabine" exactly? Options galore. 1. A Sabine dialect of Latin; 2. the Sabine language; 3. some other Sabellian (or Sabellic) language, e.g. Oscan (e.g. Sihler 1995)

**BUT** Weiss 2020: 504 is against the attribution of this etymological irregularity in Latin to Sabine (he calls it a misnomer, see footnote 63 re "the Sabine l theory" or [Poucet 1966](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41673349) calls the Sabine l theory **unacceptable** ('inacceptable'), a linguistic myth.

2. Poucet 1966 mentions Bottiglioni 1943, who reported a similar change/variation in Greek, Etruscan, Sanskrit, Iranian etc., and de Rop 1958 even in the Bantu languages.

[Kümmel 2012](https://www.academia.edu/1538887/Typology_and_reconstruction_The_consonants_and_vowels_of_Proto_Indo_European) also writes that "For  non-obstruent  stops,  it  is  well  known  that  they  sometimes  alternate with other non-obstruents, i.e., nasals or liquids (cf. Haider 1983: 86; Stewart 1989: 239f.; Clements & Rialland 2005: 18)" (p. 304) and "Therefore, sporadic alternation of PIE “mediae” with such sounds might reﬂect this state of affairs e. g.,  *d  ~  *l  in  Hitt.  dā-  vs.  Luwian  lā-  ‘to  take’."

[lingua](http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#55975) (dingua: **one** attestation only, [Mar. Vict., Keil 6.26.2](https://archive.org/details/p1grammaticilatini06keil/page/26/mode/2up)) (**Anlaut l/d variation**)

lingua < PIt. *dn̥χ(u)wā- < PIE *dnǵh-uh2 'tongue'

**Italic comparanda:** O. **fangvam** [acc.sg.], fancua [nom.pl.] 'tongue' < * fənχu̯ā- < * dh -

**IE comparanda:** OIr. tengae, MW tafawt 'tongue' < * tnǵh -, Skt. jihvā- 'id.', Av. hizuuā-, Arm. lezow, OPr. insuwis, Lith. liežuvìs, OCS językъ, Go. tuggo, OHG zunga, OIc. tunga < * dnǵh -, ToA käntu, ToB kantwo 'tongue' << * tänkwo.

**Comments**: How reasonable would it be to posit a *dl reconstruction for Latin lingua taking into account its IE comparanda?

### An afterthought

The most promising approach imho is best summarized by [Burman 2018](https://www.repository.cam.ac.uk/handle/1810/271510):

> "Even if  the theory of  Sabine *l* is no longer considered credible, modern scholarship still struggles to find a definite explanation of  a handful of  examples of  Latin /l/ where /d/ is expected. A possible reason for our inability to find a unified answer for *d/l* variation in Latin is that there may not be one. *Lingua* has been given a plausible individual explanation through analogy to *lingere*. The solutions to the problem of  *lacrima*, *oleo*, *levir*, *solium* and *malus* may be easier  to  find  if  we  approach  the  words  individually  instead  of  as  examples  of  the  same change" (p. 58).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how well-accepted this theory is, but Fournet proposes a relationship between `[d]` (*) and `/l/` in Etruscan: Hurrian *-da* ~ Etruscan *-l* "[dative marker]", Umbrian **daukomṇ* > Etruscan *lauχum* "leader", Etruscan *tular* "boundary stones" > Latin *Tuder* "[city in Umbria]".

According to him, Etruscan influences could explain the irregular change of initial `/d/` > `/l/` in Latin: see also *littera* vs Greek *diphthera*, *laurus* vs Greek *daphnē*.

(*) `[d]` instead of `/d/` because Etruscan had no voicing distinctions.

(Source: Arnaud Fournet, *A Tentative Etymological Glossary of Etruscan*, in *The Macro-Comparative Journal* 3.2)

Answer (score 5):

The big problem with the apparent cases of *d > l in Latin is working out which of them are reliable. In the late 19th century there was a vogue for trying to identify cases, most of which are now untrustworthy because of improvements in our understanding of Indo-European and Latin etymology, sound change, and morphology. This was triggered by Conway (1893), who was the first to discuss the question in detail, and also to identify the origin as borrowing from Sabine (on extremely weak grounds, as noted by Poucet). There are dozens of supposed cases in Petr (1899).

Many other examples are only known from ancient grammatical and lexicographical works, and these are not necessarily to be trusted in this context. I have tried to explain why this is in Zair (2019), where I talk about some of the instances involving apparent *d > l.

I go back and forth on which examples are plausible, but I would say that the following cannot easily be explained away:
word-initial: *dacrima > *lacrima* ‘tear’, *daywēr > *laeuir* ‘son-in-law’
word-medial: *odeō > *oleo* ‘I smell’, *sod-yo- > *solium* ‘throne’

As I noted in 2012, and Prosper also does, the word-initial examples are both followed by *a; there are also some other examples which she adduces and which I am (now) more sceptical of. But you can’t propose a straightforward change *da- to la-, because of *daps* ‘feast’, *damnum* ‘damage’. I don’t find Prosper’s approach to solving this problem entirely plausible.

References

Conway, R. Seymour (1893). On the change of d to l in Italic (*lacrima*, *levir*, *lingua*, *olfacere* etc. Mod. Italian *cicala*, *caluco* etc.). *Indogermanische Forschungen* 2, 157-67

Petr, V. J. (1899). Über den Wechsel der Laute d und l im Lateinischen. *Beiträge zur Kunder der indogermanischen Sprachen* 25, 127-58

Zair, Nicholas (2019). ‘Reconstructed forms in the Roman writers on language’. *Language and History* 62, 227-46

Comment: Wow, I never expected I would get an answer written by one of the sources that I cited! Thank you for the updated summary of this topic and the pointers to further references.

Comment: Well, yes, you can propose such a change, dear Nick, if the single exception, *dap- (by the way the only plausible etymology of lapio), has been strongly influenced by the considerable amount of Greek loanwords of the same origin: dapino, dapsilis and dapsalis.

Answer (score 4):

For ease of reference, here's de Vaan's entry for *lacruma*.

[image]

Comment: also see **scripturae** in the TLL entry http://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#54309

Answer (score 3):

Other sources I've found since posting the question:

#### Prósper

"[What became of "Sabine l"? An overlooked Proto-Italic sound law](https://www.academia.edu/40366912/What_became_of_Sabine_l_An_overlooked_Proto-Italic_sound_law)", The Journal of Indo-European Studies, 2019, Blanca María Prósper

Has a long discussion of why not to attribute d/l variation to a "Sabine" sound change.

Prósper argues that Latin had a regular sound change of *#daC, *#dāC > #laC, #lāC; examples of word-medial d/l variation in forms like *solium* are attributed to a separate, sporadic change that was conditioned by a following front vocoid (p. 468).

The phonetic evolution of the change is supposed to have been from an implosive [ɗ] (reconstructed for Proto-Italic #d) > [ˀḷ] > [l] (470-471).

Prósper proposes a number of further etymologies with #da > #la; here's a partial list:

- *deh₂i-t- > laetus
- *deh₂i-tor > Laetōrius
- *dh̥₂-tēr > latēr
- deh₂i-dʰh₁-e/o- > laedō
- deh₂-es- > lār
- deh₂-mn̥ > lāmina
- dh̥₂p- > lapiō
  -dh̥₂-tu > latus

[...]

#### Zair

I found a two-page abstract "[(False) etymology and 'Sabine -l-'](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/19645790/false-etymology-and-sabine-l-nicholas-zair-cambridge-)", by Nicholas Zair, that seems to have some of the same conclusions as Prósper's paper (that the idea of a "Sabine" origin is mistaken; that examples of d/l variation can be divided into two main contexts, word-initially before [a] and word-internally before a front vowel).

The author's [web page](http://naz21.user.srcf.net/research.html) mentions a podcast to which  d_e has given me the link: https://video.ku.dk/etymology-and-the-european-lexicon-part-30-false

Comment: "the idea of a "Sabine" origin is mistaken" - Neither Prósper nor Zair came up with this idea - see Poucet 1966 (almost sixty years ago!)

Comment: @AlexB.: Yes, that part seems to have pretty widespread agreement.

Comment: Also, I skimmed Prósper - does she simply choose to discard (or invalidate) the language data her hypothesis cannot explain - "if dacruma is real" etc.?

Comment: @AlexB.: Both Prósper and Zair seem to be skeptical of the authenticity of dacruma, dingua as preserved archaic Italic forms. Prósper does attempt to give some explanation of their presence in things like grammarian's discussions by proposing that Latin speakers noticed the correlation between Latin #la- and Greek #da- in the pair lacrima, δάκρυ(ον) and so "dacruma" would represent a Graecized or a hypothetical, etymologized form of lacrima

Comment: I particularly like “all  this  casts  many  doubts  on  the traditional  reconstruction  of  the  IE  stop  system” - I wonder how many times I’ve seen this argument used before ...

Comment: Even though I disagree with Prosper, I’ll upvote your answer.